# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 with windows

Tags: networking, mysql

I found similar questions but none of them helped me with a Windows machine. I originally posted this on stack overflow but it was suggested that I ask here.

I was able to connect to MySQL through my local machine. However, I have placed MySQL on a remote machine and when I try to connect to it from the local, I get the following error:

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Im using SQL workbench to connect. I use the remote machine's actual name for the hostname and using port 139. I have MySQL started up as a service on the remote machine as well. When googling the error I get lots of jazz about editing a file in `/etc/hosts.allow` and `my.cnf` and whatnot. However, these locations were specified for Linux machines. I have a Windows 7 machine for both my local and the remote machine and therefore do not have these locations.

Any help with connecting to MySQL would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Port 139?  That's the NetBIOS port.  MySQL runs on port 3306 by default.

Comment: For whatever reason, when checking netstat -na it shows it is listening on port 139, not 3306. I tried 3306 and the connection fails immediately.

Comment: What is your MySQL configuration?

Comment: With the initial setup config wizard I did the following:
Selected Detailed configuration, Developer Machine, Multifunctional database, decision support (up to 20 connections), Enabled TCP/IP and Stricts Mode (I did make the port number 3306), and a standard character set

Comment: I would assume that you are facing the permission issue. Double-check the permissions and accounts.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=10835

Note to self: When setting up SSH, you MUST set the following option in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

If you don't, then your packets will be silently dropped at the server. This results in the above error message.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. 'root' was pointing to the root of the local machine and the root user on the remote machine was pointing to itself. So I had it connect to an admin user and it connected fine with no errors. Thanks for for the responses and help guys.

Answer (score 0):

My use case: I was trying to access MariaDB v10 on the Synology NAS using MySQL Workbench.

Summary of the resolution:

> I found this to be a simple access grant issue to the user.

Note: Please substitute the users as necessary

**Step 1: Login to MySQL**

```
mysql -u root -p
```

**Step 2: GRANT Remote Access**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY '[Password]' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Note: My MariaDB server had multiple IPs, they all had prefix 192.168.1.* and that's why above. If your's a single IP feel free to use that in place of this. ie: @'192.168.1.111.%'

**Step 3: Apply Changes**

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Give it a quick check

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE Host <> 'localhost';
```

This step is essential. In my case, I went around changing firewalls, when the real case was this. Even in the MariaDB documentation below didn't mention this.

References:

1. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/
2. https://kb.synology.com/en-me/DSM/tutorial/Can_MariaDB_settings_be_customized_on_Synology_NAS